# Can ANTLR4 generate shared code when using an imported grammar?

Tags: antlr4

I have two languages, call them A and B (with AGrammar.g4, BGrammar.g4, ALexer.g4, and BLexer.g4). B is a superset of A and thus I have B importing A.

I have visitor code that compiles A to language X.

I am writing visitor code to compile B to language X, and want to re-use the A2X code.  However, the generated B.java code re-defines all the nested rule classes that are already in A.java

Is there any way to get B.java to re-use the generated code in A.java so I don't have to duplicate all the A visitor code?

Comment: No.  And not enough information provided to suggest alternatives. Eg:  If BLang really is a superset of ALang, you would be able to use a single grammar to process both. Why won't that work? To avoid duplicating the AVisitor code, let BVisitor extend AVisitor.  Why won't that work?

Comment: The short answer is that I want to have ALang isolated & available independently of BLang (ALang is part of a Standard, BLang contains our extensions).  BVisitor can't extend AVisitor because AVisitor has visitExpr(AGrammar.ExprContext ctx) and BVisitor has visitExpr(BGrammar.ExprContext ctx) -- there are two nested static classes generated for the AGrammar rule expr